# Efficient way to find power in Swift

Tags: swift

Just started learning Swift, I am looking for the best way to find the power in Swift language. Appreciate your feedback on this topic.

```
var a:Int = 3
var b:Int = 3 
println( pow(a,b) ) // approach 1
println(a * a * a) // approach 2
```

Is multiplying recursively a better approach than calling the system pow() and in which case(s)?

Case 1: When b is relatively small

Case 2: When b is large

Comment: Unless you have a very specific reason not to, use the system library. Also, your usage of `println` suggests you're working with/looking at code witten for Swift 1? That's way outdated.

Comment: The best option is always to measure. Try each 100000x in a loop and see how long it takes. Better still, don't get hung up on stuff like this. Write code that is readable, then figure out where your bottlenecks are by profiling, _then_ optimize.

Comment: @Gereon: the purpose behind this I am trying to figure out the efficiency of various mathematical operations comparing in C, Python and Swift. People claim that Swift is better at differentiation than Python. The way the power function is implemented in C is using a series formulation. I was just curious on a Sunday afternoon. Thanks for your feedback. I will share the github repo If I see some noticeable stuff.

Comment: @dandan78 In python the recursive approach works, even when b = 10000, whereas the system call gives an overflow error.

Comment: @SambitTripathy I would expect the speed of such operations to depend on the implementation/compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`pow` doesn't work on integers.

```swift
public extension Numeric {
  /// Raise this base to a `power`.
  func toThe<Power: UnsignedInteger>(_ power: Power) -> Self
  where Power.Stride: SignedInteger {
    power == 0
    ? 1
    : (1..<power).reduce(self) { result, _ in result * self }
  }
}
```

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(3.toThe(3 as UInt), 27)
XCTAssertEqual(1.toThe(4 as UInt), 1)
XCTAssertEqual(0.toThe(5 as UInt), 0)
XCTAssertEqual(0.toThe(0 as UInt), 1)
```